# asp net get dynanic tag height in javascript

Tags: asp.net, tags

in javascript
this is simple code

```
function fnInsertTag(tag) 
{
   tag.children().each(function () 
   {
      if ([MainTag].height() + $(this).height() >= ([page_height] - 15)) 
      {
         if ($(this).prop('tagName').toLowerCase() == 'div')
         {
            var empty_tag = $(this).clone();
            // add tag to [MainTag]
            [MainTag].append(empty_tag);
            fnInsertTag($(this));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

i want to add tag in `[MainTag]`
it so great, and work well in slow performance computer(or slow condition) 
but in nomal condition(or fast condition) code can't get `[MainTag].height()` and `$(this).height()` 
i don't know why 
some time (in slow condition) do well 
some time (in nomal,fast condition) don't well

can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you change append code to     [MainTag].promise().done( function() { append(empty_tag);}); and revert back, creating a https://jsfiddle.net/ will also help?

Answer (score 0):

Change append tag to complete earlier queued tasks, [promise()](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) may be used.

```
[MainTag].promise().done(
  function() { 
    [MainTag].append(empty_tag);
 });
```

Refer working [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anilk/Ps9g6/)

**Code, I have used to test the problem**

```
function fnInsertTag(tag) 
{
   tag.children().each(function () 
   {


      if (jQuery("#MainTag").height() + $(this).height() >= (page_height - 15)) 
      {
      page_height = jQuery("#MainTag").height() + $(this).height() ;
         if ($(this).prop('tagName').toLowerCase() == 'div')
         {
            var empty_tag = $(this).clone();
            // add tag to [MainTag]
            jQuery("#MainTag").promise().done(
            function() { jQuery("#MainTag").append(empty_tag);});
            fnInsertTag($(this));
         }
      }
   });
   }
```